# I need the route data in a node client between client to correct connected user

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, irc

I am trying to build a gnuchess web api and bind it to a graphical web interface. Trought a websocket the users will connect and when connecting the server-websocket will launch a "gnuchess" as subprocess. Then I would like to communicate with the gnuchess's stdin/stdout and send the stream to the user. But as the code is today it only starts new gnuchess's but I could only write to one of them (with all connected clients I could do that)

I have this code node-code:

```
var http = require("http");
var ws = require("./");
var fs = require("fs");
var process = require('child_process');
theglobal = "";
var ls = "";
// Web server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        fs.createReadStream("index.html").pipe(res)
}).listen(8080);

// Socket stuff
var server = ws.createServer(function (connection) {
    connection.on("text", function (str) {
        var tmp_cmd = str.split(" ")[0];
        var tmp_string = str.substr(str.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        console.log(tmp_cmd)
        console.log(tmp_string)
        if (tmp_cmd == "move") {
            ls.stdin.write(tmp_string + "\n");

            connection.sendText(str);
        }
        if (str == "start") {
            connection.sendText(str);
            ls = process.spawn('/usr/games/gnuchess');
            ls.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
                broadcast(chunk)
    });
       }
    })


});

server.listen(8081);

// Functions

// This broadcasts to all clients connected
function broadcast(str) {
        server.connections.forEach(function (connection) {
                connection.sendText(str)
        })
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Chat example</title>
<script>
var connection
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var nickname = prompt("Choose a nickname")
    if (nickname) {
        connection = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.hostname+":8081")
        connection.onopen = function () {
            console.log("Connection opened")
            connection.send(nickname)
            document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function (event) {
                var msg = document.getElementById("msg")
                if (msg.value)
                    connection.send(msg.value)
                msg.value = ""
                event.preventDefault()
            }   
        }
        connection.onclose = function () {
            console.log("Connection closed")
        }
        connection.onerror = function () {
            console.error("Connection error")
        }
        connection.onmessage = function (event) {
            var div = document.createElement("div")
            div.textContent = event.data
            document.body.appendChild(div)
        }
    }
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form">
Message: <input size="50" id="msg"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But what happens is that it starts a new gnuchess for every user who connects (it should be like that) but the data routes to the first openeded gnuchess.

Could solve the problem by using a IRC bot and IRC server and use different channel for each game (#gnuchess_user1, #gnuchess_user2, etc..) But I think it's easier actually to solve it by making a method or own object for each user and route it in the websocket.

Comment: This is the graphical interface I will use: http://gun.gnudesk.com

Comment: Hello @Alexander Karlsson. Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to do? What have you tried? What doesn't work? What question precisely can we answer so that you be in your way? Also, you may consider inlining your code, SO has excellent support for that.

Comment: Hello @dsign I would like to make one object in the server for every connected person and then bind a gnuchess-application to each of that objects. So I could communicate with the user that way. Now it's only possible to play one instance of gnuchess at once. (But it's possible to start many of gnuchess). What it should be like is that user connects to the websocket, then the server launched a gnuchess and writes output from it to the user and the user could send output to gnuchess.

Comment: Btw. Thanks @dsign for the feedback :-) Now I have edited and inlined the code

Comment: It looks much better now, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to make "ls" a local variable? By having it as part of the closure, all the clients will share  the same value of it. What about having it just before "connection.on("text", function(...))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at socket.io, it has built in support for rooms:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

Which means you can broadcast to all sockets connected to that room. You don't have to spawn separate processes for these (it will be devastating for your performance..)

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

http://socket.io

Comment: Hello Christian. That's a cool library there! I think the OP would definitely find it useful. But I don't think [gnuchess](http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/manual/html_node/Invoking-gnuchess.html#Invoking-gnuchess) can work as a multi-user "chess thinker". And well, it may be a good idea to get things running smoothly before even start worrying about performance.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is really what I need to not have to use IRC :-)

Comment: I've rebuilt the application now :-) The new code is at my Github. Now I will connect it to a already done interface :-)